# Parse error syntax error, unexpected ? [php 7.1.3]

Tags: php, symfony, null-coalescing-operator

Hello i know this problem has been answer a lot but not if i have the newer version of php and i still get this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected "?"

This error comes from my autoloader in symfony.

My composer .json and .lock both say 7.1.3

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",`
```

I tried just getting the phpinfo..but for some reason that wont work either

```
phpinfo();
die();
```

This wont return anything.

Here is smyfonys index.php the error apears at the second and third if statment.

```
<?php

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require dirname(__DIR__).'/config/bootstrap.php';

if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
    umask(0000);

    Debug::enable();
}

if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
}

if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedHosts([$trustedHosts]);
}

$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

What i discovered is, that on my windows pc with xampp and `7.3.1` my sever works no problem.

Om my mac with MAMP with `7.1.3` it does not work..
The idea is that both json and phpstorm are set to 7.1 
So this is why i am very confused....

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked that it is really executed with 7.1?

Comment: The only explanation is that your application is not served using PHP 7. How exactly do you serve the website?

Comment: How does one do that ? @kuh-chan  ... i mean i tried with phpinfo

Comment: Looks like MAMP with `7.1.3` doesn't actually run `7.1.3` but something lower, that doesn't support the null coalesce operator. Perhaps you can output the version of php in your index.php using the phpversion() function.`var_dump(phpversion())`

Comment: How do you execute your files?

Comment: Well im on 5.3.29 great stuff. Thank you.. @Webber Add it an answer if you want, so i can accept it.

Comment: @roibuble You're welcome. I added the above comment + symfony documentation for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like MAMP with `7.1.3` doesn't actually run `7.1.3` but something lower, that doesn't support the `null coalesce` operator. Perhaps you can output the version of php in your `index.php` using the `phpversion()` function. `var_dump(phpversion())`

When using Symfony, it might also be useful to check if your system is setup properly using their requirements checker: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html

Comment: different versions can be configured: https://www.mamp.info/en/release-notes/mac/ ...which might be the actual culprit.